# Exporting image through ContentProvider

Tags: android, bitmap, export, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I´m trying to export an image from my application to other applications like twitter, facebook or other apps accepting it images.
I'm doing the following:

```
private void exportImage()
{
    storeBitmapOnDisk(this.bitmap);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    File imgFile = context.getFileStreamPath("export.png");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imgFile);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    i.setType("image/png");
    i.setComponent(componentName);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
private void storeBitmapOnDisk(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream outStream = context.openFileOutput("export.png",
        Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, outStream);
        outStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is not working because I'm writing internal storage with is not accessible by other applications. As I don't want to use external storage (SD card) I think what I need is a ContentProvider but all examples I saw is about custom ContentPovider are using a SQlite database to store the data. I can't figure out how I could store a bitmap in internal storage and make it available through a ContentProvider to other applications without storing my bitmap in a database. MatrixCursor seems not to be adapted too...

**SOLUTION**  I create a custom Content Provider and set the path of the file in the the content provider as the Uri EXTRA_STREAM extra parameter of the intent:

First my provider class where I only needed to override **openFile** which is not clear in the doc...

```
public class ExportContentProvider extends ContentProvider
{
  public static Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri
                                    .parse("content://com.path.to.my.provider");

  @Override
  public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public String getType(Uri uri)
  {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values)
  {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreate()
  {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)
  {
    int imode = 0;
    if (mode.contains("w"))
      imode |= ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_WRITE_ONLY;
    if (mode.contains("r"))
      imode |= ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY;
    if (mode.contains("+"))
      imode |= ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_APPEND;
    try
    {
      return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(uri.getEncodedPath()), imode);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
      String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
  {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
      String[] selectionArgs)
  {
      return 0;
  }
}
```

And then my export function:

```
private void exportImage()
{
    storeBitmapOnDisk();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.withAppendedPath(
        ExportContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, context.getFileStreamPath(
            "export.png").getAbsolutePath()));
    i.setType("image/png");
    i.setComponent(componentName);
    if (exportFileObserver == null)
    {
      this.bitmapPath = context.getFileStreamPath("export.png")
          .getAbsolutePath();
      exportFileObserver = new ExportFileObserver(this.bitmapPath);
      exportFileObserver.startWatching();
    }
    listener.launchExportActivity(Dms.ACT_IMAGE_EXPORT, i);
  }
```

Nevertheless there are 2 problems remaining:
- When trying to delete my temporary export.png file on my internal memory using result of the activity I received the onResult when the activity is launch...
- It s not working for mail app in my 2.3 emulator. I'm getting "File to large" message...

Somenone tested that ?